# Compute vector that points inside of a curve

Tags: parametric, curvature

I am implementing a trajectory tracking algorithm, and I am having trouble computing the angle the robot should follow when there is a change in curvature. I think that using the vector that points inside the curvature could be really useful, but I do not know how to computer this vector.

Basically I need to compute the blue vector of [this animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#/media/File:Lemniscate_nebeneinander_animated.gif). Any ideas how I can compute this vector when I know the parametric equations of the curve.

Comment: The acceleration vector is the second derivative of the position vector over time.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thank you. I thought it was the acceleration of the curvature or something different since it is shown as 'acceleartion vector'